# Confidence vs credible interval for binomial probability

Tags: r, confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, credible-interval

I have two related questions regarding the calculation of confidence intervals for a binomial probability and how they relate to credible intervals. (This must have appeared a thousand times- apologies).

While looking at R code for [binom.test](https://rdrr.io/r/stats/binom.test.html) I noticed that the 95% confidence interval for the probability of success given the number of success and failures is:

$$
CI_{0.025} = BetaCdf^{-1}(p= 0.025 | \alpha= \text{n_succ}, \beta= \text{n_fail + 1}) \\
CI_{0.975} = BetaCdf^{-1}(p= 0.975 | \alpha= \text{n_succ + 1}, \beta= \text{n_fail})
$$

Or in R code:

```
ci.low <- qbeta(0.025, n_succ, n_fail + 1)
ci.high <- qbeta(0.975, n_succ + 1, n_fail)
```

- First question: Why **do not** we add 1 to $n\_succ$ for calculating the lower bound of CI? (Likewise, why don't we add 1 to $n\_fail$ for the upper bound?)

I.e. my thought was that we should calculate CIs as:

$$
ci_{p} = BetaCdf^{-1}(p | \alpha= \text{n_succ + 1}, \beta= \text{n_fail + 1})
$$

In R:

```
qbeta(c(0.025, 0.975), n_succ + 1, n_fail + 1)
```

My reasoning being that $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = 1$ give a uniform prior that we update with the observed data. This procedure should give Bayesian credible intervals, right? And since we use a uniform prior credible and confidence intervals should coincide. Where is the fault in this reasoning?

- Second question:

Consider this ridiculously small experiment with 1 observation only:

```
n_succ <- 1
n_fail <- 0
```

The confidence intervals would be:

```
ci.low <- qbeta(0.025, n_succ, n_fail + 1)
ci.high <- qbeta(0.975, n_succ + 1, n_fail)
print(c(ci.low, ci.high))
# [1] 0.025 1.000
```

The range `[0.025 1]` is very wide and it seems reasonable given only one observation. However, the credible interval would be (if I'm correct):

```
 qbeta(c(0.025, 0.975), n_succ + 1, n_fail + 1)
 # [1] 0.158 0.987
```

which seems relatively narrow to me (you are fairly convinced to exclude $p < 0.15$ with 95% probability!). How can I reconcile credible and confidence intervals? Can you explain the discrepancy?

Comment: What is $BetaCdf$ supposed to be? Are you trying to use the symbol $\beta$?

Comment: @ThePointer $BetaCDF^{-1}$ is the inverse of the cumulative distribution function for the beta distribution. In R code, it's the `qbeta` function.